# What does "solidify" meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this passage from my reference book. There is a sentence being bold below :

> The standard SSI and MSI parts that have served as “bricks and mortar”
>   in the building of digital systems for over 40 years are now obsolete
>   and becoming less available. Many of the techniques that have been
>   taught over that time have focused on optimizing circuits that are
>   built from these outmoded devices. The topics that are uniquely suited
>   to applying the old technology but do not contribute to an
>   understanding of the new technology are being de-emphasized. From an
>   educational standpoint, however, these small ICs do offer a way to
>   study simple digital circuits, and the wiring of circuits using
>   breadboards is a valuable pedagogic exercise. **They help to solidify
>   concepts such as binary inputs and outputs, physical device operation,
>   and practical limitations, using a very simple platform.** Consequently, we have
>   chosen to continue to introduce the conceptual descriptions of digital circuits
>   and to offer examples using conventional standard logic parts

What does "solidify" meaning in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, 'to make more definite' ( https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/solidify ), to give the learners a more clear understanding of those concepts and their practical aspects.